# Block http requests not submitted via UI

Tags: http

This might seem like a strange question, but is it possible to detect and reject requests sent to my web server from outside my UI? For example if someone sent a post request to create a resource using the correct authorization token or session info from a tool such as Postman, could it be detected?

I want to prevent someone from using my application as some makeshift API.

Comment: Well you could check perhaps the header of the request, but that could always be spoofed.

Comment: Right. I need something unspoofable. I'm not convinced this is possible...

Comment: HTTP is an open protocol and all requests can be simulated/spoofed. It's impossible to 100% make sure whether a request comes from your UI or not.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can do is to just make sure (or come close to that) it's a human being by using a captcha service such as [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/)

Comment: I will be implementing captcha for the sign up page to ensure human account setup. Seems like the only way I may detect requests outside of the UI is perhaps reviewing logs for unusual errors like data validation or invalid requests and then banning that IP and killing that account.